# The spam filter caught my answer and I want to know why

Tags: bug, answers

I attempted to post [this answer](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/80090/20058) to [this question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/80008/how-to-concentrate-during-conference-talks-where-the-quality-of-the-presentation), and it was rejected by the spam filter. Instead of receiving any kind of detailed "remove this wording, this looks like advertising, etc." I received a blanket "this looks like spam" (pointing at the entire message).

I had no clue what I had done wrong, so I went on chat and a helpful person there gave me some tips. Ultimately it looked like the bullet point list at the end was too long for a 1-rep person such as myself (at least, that's the best I can figure). I removed the bulleted list and was able to post the answer and edit the list back in later.

Does anyone know why the heuristics went nuts and thought my answer was spam? Could this be a legitimate bug, as the person who helped me indicated?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A human reading your answer can easily judge that it is not spam. The spam filter, however, isn't human. The SE team has looked into the behavior and told the spam filter to be less aggressive in cases like these.

Getting feedback about false positives is hard, so thank you for mentioning it. I am sorry your introduction to AC.SE wasn't more pleasant.

Comment: What a helpful, courteous reply.